# Check if a OneToOne relation exists in Django

Tags: python, django, model, one-to-one

Now I'm using django 1.6

I have two models relates with a `OneToOneField`.

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    ref_a = models.OneToOneField(related_name='ref_b', null=True)
```

---

First see my code that points out the problem:

```
a1 = A.objects.create()
a2 = A.objects.create()
b1 = B.objects.create()
b2 = B.objects.create(ref_a=a2)

# then I call:
print(a1.ref_b)  # DoesNotExist Exception raised
print(a2.ref_b)  # returns b2
print(b1.ref_a)  # returns None
print(b2.ref_a)  # returns a2
```

Now the problem is, if I want to check a `A` object, to judge whether it exists a `B` objects referencing it. How can I do?

The valid way I tried is only to try and catch an exception, but is there any other prettier way?

---

My effort:

1 - The below code works, but is too ugly!

```
b = None
try:
    b = a.ref_b
except:
    pass
```

2 - I also tried to check the attributes in a, but not working:

```
b = a.ref_b if hasattr(a, 'ref_b') else None
```

---

Do you meet the same problem, friends? Please point me a way, thank you!

Comment: I think this will work for you, please keep in mind change your class name at least in 2 later. b = hasattr(a_class_object, 'b class') and a.ref_b or None. I am using same and working for me.

Comment: @Yogesh I don't quite catch, could you please post a more detail solution?

Comment: `hasattr` seems to work fine for me on Django 1.8.17 with Python 2.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

So you have a least two ways of checking that.
First is to create try/catch block to get attribute, second is to use `hasattr`.

```
class A(models.Model):
   def get_B(self):
       try:
          return self.b
       except:
          return None

class B(models.Model):
   ref_a = models.OneToOneField(related_name='ref_b', null=True)
```

Please try to avoid bare `except:` clauses. It can hide some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797375/542196).

The second way is:

```
class A(models.Model):
    def get_B(self):
       if(hasattr(self, 'b')):
           return self.b
       return None

class B(models.Model):
    ref_a = models.OneToOneField(related_name='ref_b', null=True)
```

In both cases you can use it without any exceptions:

```
a1 = A.objects.create()
a2 = A.objects.create()
b1 = B.objects.create()
b2 = B.objects.create(ref_a=a2)

# then I call:
print(a1.get_b)  # No exception raised
print(a2.get_b)  # returns b2
print(b1.a)  # returns None
print(b2.a)  # returns a2
```

There is no other way, as throwing the exception is default behaviour from Django [One to One relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

And this is the example of handling it from official documentation.

```
>>> from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
>>> try:
>>>     p2.restaurant
>>> except ObjectDoesNotExist:
>>>     print("There is no restaurant here.")
There is no restaurant here.
```

Answer (score 15):

Individual model classes provide a more specific exception called DoesNotExist that extends ObjectDoesNotExist. My preference is to write it this way:

```
b = None
try:
    b = a.ref_b
except B.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Comment: why not put `b = None` in the `except` clause? (to save a line)

Answer (score 14):

`hasattr` works fine with Django1.11 !
You may use `getattr` for shorter version:

```
getattr(self, 'field', default)
```

In your case

```
b = getattr(a, 'ref_b', None)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr

Answer (score 2):

**Much cleaner** to use custom django Field based on `OneToOneField`, this approach which will allow you to use direct access - just `a.ref_b` and result would be `instance or None`

```
from django.db.models.fields.related import ReverseOneToOneDescriptor
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db import models

class SingleRelatedObjectDescriptorReturnsNone(ReverseOneToOneDescriptor):
    def __get__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().__get__(*args, **kwargs)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

class OneToOneOrNoneField(models.OneToOneField):
    """A OneToOneField that returns None if the related object doesn't exist"""
    related_accessor_class = SingleRelatedObjectDescriptorReturnsNone
```

so the example will look like

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    ref_a = OneToOneOrNoneField(related_name='ref_b', null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending mr. Coffee answer you can use context lib suppress method

```
import contextlib

class A(models.Model):
    def get_B(self):
       with contextlib.suppress(Exception):
           return self.b

class B(models.Model):
    ref_a = models.OneToOneField(related_name='ref_b', null=True)
```