# How can I delete a django reverse OneToOne-Relation and then reuse the model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Say I have these models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    onetoone = OneToOneField(MyModel)
```

If `obj` here is of type `MyModel`, how can i then delete the `onetoone` such that I can use the `hasattr`-check later to find out that the onetoone does not exist any more?
Is there some other way to find out that the `onetoone` has been deleted?

```
obj.onetoone.delete()
hasattr(obj, "onetoone")  # This still returns True, but actually it should return False
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve here? are you trying to remove a relationship?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to remove the relationship and delete the related object. Afterwards, I want the check to return False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `refresh_from_db` of the related instance should do. You can make it transparent by overriding `delete` of the dependent model.

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    onetoone = OneToOneField(MyModel)

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        result = self.delete(using, keep_parents)
        self.onetoone.refresh_from_db()
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The `hasattr` will always return True, even if you've never created the relationship in the first place. It is not the right thing to be using here.

Instead, you need to check whether there is a related object.

```
try:
    obj.onetoone
except OtherModel.DoesNotExist:
    print("does not exist")
```

Comment: The first answer here however says that one can use `hasattr`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944968/check-if-a-onetoone-relation-exists-in-django