# Django user record not found

Tags: python, django

I am trying to extend the user model in django by using a Client model (this might not be the ideal way, but that boat has sailed). When I try to access a user record in a template I get the error:

```
No Client matches the given query
```

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def update_client_details(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        # print('pk', user.pk)
        client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=user.pk)
```

If I print the user.pk I see what I expect.

Why doesn't it return an object?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `user.pk` in `get_object_or_404(Client, pk=user.pk)` as it will try to find `pk` in `Client` model but In client model there where no any data available as per given primary key in `get_object_or_404(Client, pk=user.pk)` because this `pk` is user's `pk`.

So, if you want to get object as per `user` the you have to write as below...

```
client = get_object_or_404(Client, user=user)
```

Or you can use as simple way...

```
client_obj = Client.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because, you queried on Client model with User model id.
you can use this query

```
client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=user.pk)
```

instead of

```
client = get_object_or_404(Client, user=user)
```

If you want to check whether any client exist related with request.user you can use following queries:

```
client = Client.objects.filter(user=request.user).first() 
# this query returns None if there is no client related with your user.
if client:
    #your update processes
else:
    # your client not exist commands
```

you can use also `hasattr` method. There is a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27042585/7659834)

Comment: Have you client record related with this user in your database?Can you check it?

Comment: Ahhhh! never thought of that. So I need to check and create if it doesn't exist?

Comment: It depends on your program logic totaly. But I think you shouldn't check it here. Because your view about update process. But you can check is there any client related request.user object

Comment: Yes, the user object is there, see my question, I can print user.pk

Comment: Yes,you have user object but you may not have defined any clent connected to the user. You must check it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to do that. I thought that was achieved by client = get_object...

Comment: I added how can you check client codes. Please look at answer again:)

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317816/relatedobjectdoesnotexist-user-has-no-userprofile/36317833#36317833) I realised that I needed to add:

```
profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

to **views.py**

So **views.py** now looks like:

```
def update_client_details(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

and I have access to user and profile data

The profile for a user is created if it doesn't exist