# python return multiple times

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using **Scrapy** to scrape data [this site](https://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/fl/miami-dade-county/kvc-17_1,17_3,17_2,17_8/incl-22/). I need to call `getlink`from `parse`. Normal call is not working as well when  use `yield`, i get this error:

```
2015-11-16 10:12:34 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'generator' in <GET https://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/fl/miami-dad
```

e-county/kvc-17_1,17_3,17_2,17_8/incl-22/>

Returning `getlink` function from `parse` works but i need to execute some code even after returning. I'm confused any help would be really appreciable.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.http import Request,Response
    import re
    import csv
    import time

    from selenium import webdriver



    class ColdWellSpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "cwspider"
        allowed_domains = ["coldwellbankerhomes.com"]
        #start_urls = [''.join(row).strip() for row in csv.reader(open("remaining_links.csv"))]
        #start_urls = ['https://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/fl/boynton-beach/5451-verona-drive-unit-d/pid_9266204/']
        start_urls = ['https://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/fl/miami-dade-county/kvc-17_1,17_3,17_2,17_8/incl-22/']

        def parse(self,response):

                #browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--load-images=false'])
                browser = webdriver.Firefox()
                browser.maximize_window()
                browser.get(response.url)
                time.sleep(5)

                #to extract all the links from a page and send request to those links
                #this works but even after returning i need to execute the while loop
                return self.getlink(response)

                #for clicking the load more button in the page 
                while True:
                    try:
                        browser.find_element_by_class_name('search-results-load-more').find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
                        time.sleep(3)
                        self.getlink(response)

                    except:
                        break

        def getlink(self,response):
            print 'hhelo'

            c = open('data_getlink.csv', 'a')
            d = csv.writer(c, lineterminator='\n')
            print 'hello2'
            listclass = response.xpath('//div[@class="list-items"]/div[contains(@id,"snapshot")]')

            for l in listclass:
                   link = 'http://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/'+''.join(l.xpath('./h2/a/@href').extract())

                   d.writerow([link])
                   yield Request(url = str(link),callback=self.parse_link)


       #callback function of Request
       def parse_link(self,response):
                b = open('data_parselink.csv', 'a')
                a = csv.writer(b, lineterminator='\n')
                a.writerow([response.url])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'generator'

`getlink()` is a generator. You are trying to `yield` it from the `parse()` generator.

Instead, you can/should iterate over the results of `getlink()` call:

```
def parse(self, response):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(5)

    while True:
        try:
            for request in self.getlink(response):
                yield request

            browser.find_element_by_class_name('search-results-load-more').find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
            time.sleep(3)
        except:
            break
```

Also, I've noticed you have both `self.getlink(response)` and `self.getlink(browser)`. The latter is not gonna work since there is no `xpath()` method on a webdriver instance - you probably meant to [make a Scrapy `Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#constructing-selectors) out of the page source that your webdriver controlled browser has loaded, for example:

```
selector = scrapy.Selector(text=browser.page_source)
self.getlink(selector)
```

You should also take a look on to [Explicit Waits with Expected Conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of using unreliable and slow artificial delays via `time.sleep()`.

Plus, I'm not sure what is the reason you are writing to CSV manually instead of using built-in [Scrapy Items](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) and [Item Exporters](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html). And, you are not closing the files properly and not using the `with()` context manager either.

Additionally, try to catch more specific exception(s) and [avoid having a bare try/expect block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements).

Comment: writing csv manually is just to check if the code is working or not