# unknown error in beautifulsoup web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

```
<div id="browse_in_widget">
<span id="browse_in_breadcrumb" style="width: 583px;">
<div class="seo_itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" itemscope="">
<a itemprop="url" href="/search/"> Arabian Area</a>
<span class="seo_itemprop-title" itemprop="title">Arabian Area</span>
>
</div>
<div class="seo_itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" itemscope="">
<a itemprop="url" href="/property-for-rent/home/"> Phase 2 </a>
<span class="seo_itemprop-title" itemprop="title">Phase 2 </span>
>
</div>
<div class="seo_itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" itemscope="">
<a itemprop="url" href="/property-for-rent/residential/"> Residential Units for Rent </a>
<span class="seo_itemprop-title" itemprop="title">Residential Units for Rent</span>
>
</div>
<div class="seo_itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" itemscope="">
<a itemprop="url" href="/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/"> Apartment/Flat for Rent </a>
<span class="seo_itemprop-title" itemprop="title">Apartment/Flat for Rent</span>
>
</div>
<strong class="seo_itemprop-title" itemprop="title">Details</strong>
</span>
</div>
```

I want to get

```
['Arabian Area', 'Phase 2', 'Residential Units for Rent','Apartment/Flat for Rent']
```

I am trying to use the following code using beautiful 4 python

```
try:

        Type = [str(Area.text) for Area in soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "seo_itemscope"})]

        Area=' , '.join(Area)
        print Area


    except StandardError as e:
        Area="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print Area
```

All i want is to get the desired output in a list but there seems to be some problem. I am not getting any print. What can be the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are looking for `span` elements with `seo_itemscope` class which don't exist. Use `seo_itemprop-title` if you are looking for the titles:

```
Type = [item.get_text() for item in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "seo_itemprop-title"})]
```

The other problem is here:

> `Area=' , '.join(Area)`

You meant to join items of the `Type` list instead:

```
Area = ' , '.join(Type)
```

---

And, it is not a good idea to catch the `StandardError` - it is too broad of an exception and actually is close to having a bare `except` clause. You should catch more specific exceptions, see:

- [Should I always specify an exception type in `except` statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements)

Comment: thanks. What if i want to get only the fourth element in the list? i.e. Apartment/Flat for Rent and ignore the previous three? python allows it?

Comment: @Joanne sure, do you mean `soup.find_all("span", {"class": "seo_itemprop-title"})[3].get_text()`?

Comment: @Joanne hey, Joanne - is there anything else I can help with in this particular topic? If not, please consider marking the answer as accepted to resolve the thread. Thanks.