# Web Scraping using python from LivingSocial

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

I have to write a program that scrapes the website “LivingSocial” for all the details of their deals and promo and store it in MySQLdatabase.
URL : "http://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco"
So far I have been able to write this code :

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import MySQLdb

# connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="",
db="scrapy")

x = db.cursor()


page = requests.get('https://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of buyers:
descrip = tree.xpath('//p[@class="description"]/text()')
loc = tree.xpath('//p[@class="location"]/text()')


try:
   x.execute("""INSERT INTO scrapy VALUES (%s,%s)""",(descrip,loc))
   db.commit()
except:
   db.rollback()

db.close()
```

I have created a MySQL database using xampp server.
But this code doesn't seem to run as expected. Please help!

Comment: *doesn't seem to run as expected* Exactly what were you expecting what did you actually observe? What have your debugging attempts revealed?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are extracting descriptions and locations *independently* which would cause problems since not every deal has a location. Instead, you need to iterate over all "deals" and for each deal get the description and location:

```
deals = [
    {'description': deal.findtext('.//p[@class="description"]'),
     'location': deal.findtext('.//p[@class="location"]')}
    for deal in tree.xpath("//li[@dealid]")
]
```

Here `deals` would become a *list of dictionaries*. If no location is provided, it would be `None` (which then would become NULL in MySQL).

The next problem is to insert `deals` into the database. For it we would use `executemany()`:

```
x.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        scrapy 
    VALUES 
        (%(description)s, %(location)s)
""", deals)
db.commit()
```

---

As a side note, you should not be using the [bare except clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements) and catch more specific exceptions instead. Also, you are silently catching an error and rolling back which prevents you from knowing what happened, what error was raised. Log your errors:

```
try:
    # ...
except SomeMeaningfulException as e:
    print(e) # TODO: properly log the exception
    db.rollback()
```