# python try and exception

Tags: python

I am not a python geek but have tried to solve this problem using information from several answers to similar questions but none seem to really work in my case. Here it is:

I am calling a function from a python script:
Here is the function:

```
def getsom(X):
    #some codes
    try:
        st = get data from site 1 using X
    except:
        print "not available from site 1, getting from site 2"
        st = get data from site 2 using X

    #some codes that depend on st
```

I am calling this from a python script as such:

```
#some codes
for yr in range(min_yr,max_yr+1):
    day=1
    while day<max_day:
        st1 = getsom(X)
        #some code that depends on st1
        day+=1
```

This works fine when data is available on either site 1 or 2 for a particular day, but breaks down when it is unavailable on both sites for another day.

I want to be able to check for the next day if data is unavailable for a particular day for both sites. I have tried different configurations of try and except with no success and would appreciate any help on the most efficient way to do this.

Thanks!

***Edits
Final version that worked:

in the function part:

```
def getsom(X):
    #some codes
    try:
        st = get data from site 1 using X
    except:
        print "not available from site 1, getting from site 2"
        st = get data from site 2 using X

        try:
           st = get data from site 2 using X
        except:
           print "data not available from sites 1 and 2"
           st=None
    if st is not None:
        #some codes that depend on st
```

In order to iterate to the next day on the script side, I had to handle the none case from the function with another try/except block:

```
#some codes
for yr in range(min_yr,max_yr+1):
    day=1
    while day<max_day:


   try:
       st=getsom(X)
   except:
       st=None

    if st is not None:
       #some codes that depend
```

Comment: So, wrap the code in the `except` block in `try/except`...

Comment: Wonder why I got down-voted 4 pts in less than a minute.@ForceBru... thanks for your suggestion, I tried it but didnt seem to get it working. could you kindly give an example

Comment: the code of `getsom` is almost OK. You wrapped `st  = get data from site 1` in a `try/except` construction, and so you should do with `st = get data from site 2`. The current answer's got it correct.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you seem like you want to catch the exception *in* first-level exception handler. You can do it like this:

```
def getsom(X):
    #some codes
    try:
        st = get data from site 1 using X
    except:
        print "not available from site 1, getting from site 2"
        try:
             st = get data from site 2 using X
        except:
             print "Not available from site 2 as well."
             # Here you can assign some arbitrary value to your variable (like None for example) or return from function.

    #some codes that depend on st
```

If data is not available on neither of the sites you can assign some arbitrary value to your variable `st` or simply return from the function.

Is this what you are looking for?
Also, you shouldn't simply write `except` without specifying the type of exception you expect - look here for more info: [Should I always specify an exception type in `except` statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements)

Edit to answer the problem in comment:

If you have no data about certain day you can just `return None` and handle it like this:

```
#some codes
for yr in range(min_yr,max_yr+1):
    day=1
    while day<max_day:
        st1 = getsom(X)
        if st1 is not None:
            #some code that depends on st1
        day+=1
```

Comment: This should works but to use try...except... in another try is not recommended according to PEP8.

Comment: @grael  ... thanks all for the quick response. With the inner try/except set to return, the function works well but the script does not go to the next day but exits with: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". With st set to None (or other arb. variable), the other dependent parts of the function below the try/except block break down, as no data is found.

Comment: @grael... thanks a bunch, I modified your idea a bit and it worked! This is just part of a very long and multi-functional code. Check the edit to find the final version.

Comment: @David Page... thanks David for the best-practice suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a separate function for it?

```py
def getdata(X):
    for site in [site1, site2]:  # possibly more
        try:
            return get_data_from_site_using_X()
        except:
            print "not available in %s" % site
    print "couldn't find data anywhere"
```

Then `getsom` becomes:

```py
def getsom(X):
    #some codes
    st = getdata(X)
    #some codes that depend on st
```