# Unit test: test not failing if using try-except

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am trying to execute post-failure operations; so I can gather info on the state of the system only if it fail.

So far, I did not find a solution that works. I did try to add a try-except and this works; but then the output of my test run is "success", which is totally wrong.

```
try:
    self.assertFalse(x>1, "the test failed")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # do other post failure actions
```

Since the exception is caught, I assume that the unit test class won't be involved in reporting the error, and this end up with the test not failing.

How do I "escalate" the failure at the same time to both the except section and the Unit test class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *re-raise the exception* once you caught and recorded it:

```
try:
    self.assertFalse(x>1, "the test failed")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # do other post failure actions

    raise
```

Note that you may and should [be more specific about the error you are catching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements) - in this case, you are looking for catching the [`AssertionError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError) instead of the generic `Exception`.