# Mysql prepared statements not getting replaced with values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Have tried with both (?) and (%s) but doesn't seem to be working. Where am I gong wrong?

```
def update(phone,name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    print ("\nOpened database for updates successfully")

    sql = "UPDATE VARUN set PHONE = %s where NAME= %s "
    print (sql)
    conn.execute(sql,(phone,name))
    '''
    conn.execute("UPDATE VARUN set PHONE = (?) where NAME= (?) ",(phone,name));
    '''
    conn.commit()
```

----- calling function ----

```
contactlist[selection()]=[nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get()]
updt = (contactlist[selection()])
name = (updt[0])
phone = (updt[1])
print (name,phone)

try:
    update(name,phone)
except:
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("cannot be blank")
else:

    setList ()
    saveContact()
```

Comment: `conn.execute('UPDATE VARUN set PHONE = ? where NAME = ?', (phone, name))` should work fine.

Comment: @poke  Thanks for pointing that out.  But it still doesn't update in the database. Can let know how can i debug this? All other operations like insert are working fine, so there is problem with the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using a [bare except clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797375/771848) which prevents you from seeing what errors are thrown from the function. Remove it and see how it fails.

And, you need to have `?` placeholders without the surrounding parenthesis:

```
def update(phone, name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print ("\nOpened database for updates successfully")

    sql = "UPDATE VARUN set PHONE = ? where NAME= ?"
    cursor.execute(sql, (phone, name))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm not getting any errors after changing it but it still doesn't update in the database. Can let know how can i debug this? All other operations like insert are working fine, so there is problem with the database.

Comment: @Varun well, make sure you are actually updating the same table in the same database as you are checking the results in. I've also noticed that the title says about mysql but there is sqlite3 connection code posted..thanks.

Comment: I cross checked and everything seems to be fine. But somehow it doesn't insert. Is there a way to print the query being executed? I tried converting it to string and print but it still prints as object.