# PEP8 Does Not Allow Try Except Block

Tags: python, pep8

My code contains a regular try-except block. I downloaded the pycodestyle library to test pep8 on my code. I tested my code and I got the following PEP8 error:

```
E722 do not use bare 'except'
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because I was specifically referring to PEP8 guidelines not whether it's a good practice.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking. That rule is explicitly stated in PEP8, have you read it?

Comment: You are right; it is a duplicate. Apologies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should include a specific exception.

For example,

```
try:
   <stuff>
except IndexError:
   <stuff>
```

Instead of

```
try:
   <stuff>
except:
   <stuff>
```

It helps with debugging - you'll know if an unexpected error pops up, and the error won't fly by possibly messing something else up.

Comment: [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797508/6947337) goes into more detail as to why specifying exceptions is a good idea.

Comment: Is it reasonable to ignore this rule if you have a top level try-except to make sure unexpected errors are redirected to a logger and/or a remote monitoring service?

Comment: In that case you could use `except Exception as e:` so you know what the error is