# Python try/except not catching exception with requests.get()

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.4 on a Raspberry Pi to upload weather data to a website. Sometime there's a problem uploading (slow Internet or something) and my program crashes. I'm using try/except, but for some reason it's not catching the error. I thought the the last except statement should catch any other errors.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 364, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 577, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 804, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:584: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 306, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='rtupdate.wunderground.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Weather_Station/WU_upload.py", line 52, in upload2WU
    r = requests.get(full_URL, timeout=5) # send data to WU
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='rtupdate.wunderground.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Weather_Station/Weather_Station.py", line 381, in <module>
    uploadStatus = WU_upload.upload2WU(suntec, WU_STATION)
  File "/home/pi/Weather_Station/WU_upload.py", line 65, in upload2WU
    except requests.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NewConnectionError'
>>>
```

Here's my code:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(full_URL, timeout=5) # send data to WU

    # If uploaded successfully, website will reply with 200
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return(True)
    else:
        print('Upload Error: {}  {}'.format(r.status_code, r.text))
        return(False)

except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - ConnectionError")
    return(False)

except requests.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - NewConnectionError")
    return(False)

except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - ReadTimeout")
    return(False)

except requests.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - MaxRetryError")
    return(False)

except socket.gaierror:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - socket.gaierror")
    return(False)

except:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - other")
    return(False)
```

Comment: Please read the error message carefully - especially the part about `AttributeError`

Comment: There isn't a `NewConnectionError` exception in `requests.exception`. [Check the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/)

Comment: btw, don't use `except` alone: always use `except Exception` at least. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797393/8784382)

Comment: Thanks.  I removed `NewConnectionError` and and added one for `Timeout` and the program catches the Timeout error and keeps on going.