# how to convert types while keeping the same list structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this list here:

```
[['Afghanistan', '2.66171813', '7.460143566', '0.490880072', '52.33952713', '0.427010864', '-0.106340349', '0.261178523'], ['Albania', '4.639548302', '9.373718262', '0.637698293', '69.05165863', '0.74961102', '-0.035140377', '0.457737535'], ['Algeria', '5.248912334', '9.540244102', '0.806753874', '65.69918823', '0.436670482', '-0.194670126', ''], ['Argentina', '6.039330006', '9.843519211', '0.906699121', '67.53870392', '0.831966162', '-0.186299905', '0.305430293'], ['Armenia', '4.287736416', '9.034710884', '0.697924912', '65.12568665', '0.613697052', '-0.132166177', '0.246900991'], ['Australia', '7.25703764', '10.71182728', '0.949957848', '72.78334045', '0.910550177', '0.301693261', '0.45340696']]
```

My aim is to loop through the list of lists and convert number string values to integers.

I tried

```
for li in main_li:
    for element in li:
        if element == li[0]:
            continue
        else:
            element = int(element)
```

My problem is how can I get this back into the same list format I had above without the numbers being strings.

Comment: your string numbers are float not integer , you want them to be round or something?

Comment: what's your desired output ?

Comment: Your code does not modify the original list. Because you are assigning a new value to a loop variable not to an index in the list.

Comment: You have an empty string `‘‘` at the end of the third sublist with ‘Algeria’. I suppose it shouldn’t be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't (not saying it's not possible) change list values while you loop over them. You'll have to create a new list. Fortunately, you can do it very easily with a small modification to your original code:

```
newlist = []
for li in main_li:
    newli = []
    for element in li:
        if element == li[0]:
            newli.append(element)
        else:
            try:
                newli.append(int(float(element)))
            except Exception as e:
                newli.append(0) # This is added because not everything in your list can be converted to int.
    newlist.append(newli)
```

`newlist` will be your modified list of lists.

Alternatively, you can use list comprehension:

```
newlist = [[p[0]] + [int(float(x)) for x in p[1:]] for p in main_li]
```

Note how this requires all of your string to be correctly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by making a small change in your code

```
for li in main_li:
for i in range(1,len(li)):
    try:
        li[i] = int(li[i])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the catch-all except. It often ends badly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements

Answer (score 1):

Your list elements are float so you can only convert them to float:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?') # a pattern for all number types
new_list = []
for nest in l:
    temp_list = []
    for val in nest:
        if bool(pattern.match(val)): #check if the element is a number
            temp_list.append(float(val))
            continue
        temp_list.append(val)
    new_list.append(temp_list)  
print(new_list)
[['Afghanistan', 2.66171813, 7.460143566, 0.490880072, 52.33952713, 0.427010864, -0.106340349, 0.261178523], ['Albania', 4.639548302, 9.373718262, 0.637698293, 69.05165863, 0.74961102, -0.035140377, 0.457737535], ['Algeria', 5.248912334, 9.540244102, 0.806753874, 65.69918823, 0.436670482, -0.194670126, ''], ['Argentina', 6.039330006, 9.843519211, 0.906699121, 67.53870392, 0.831966162, -0.186299905, 0.305430293], ['Armenia', 4.287736416, 9.034710884, 0.697924912, 65.12568665, 0.613697052, -0.132166177, 0.246900991], ['Australia', 7.25703764, 10.71182728, 0.949957848, 72.78334045, 0.910550177, 0.301693261, 0.45340696]]
```

Comment: Your approach doesn't cover negative numbers and also broke the list format.

Comment: In Python, "inf", "infinity", "NaN" and exponential notation ("1.23E4") are all strings that can be converted to floating values. Those cases are niet caught by your regex...

Answer (score 0):

Simply just convert those elements that are convertible to float and change them in current list with iterating through list index:

```
for i in range(len(main_li)):
    for j in range(len(main_li[i])):
        try:
            main_li[i][j] = float(main_li[i][j])
        except ValueError:
            continue


li # [['Afghanistan', 2.66171813, 7.460143566, 0.490880072, 52.33952713, 0.427010864, -0.106340349, 0.261178523], ['Albania', 4.639548302, 9.373718262, 0.637698293, 69.05165863, 0.74961102, -0.035140377, 0.457737535], ['Algeria', 5.248912334, 9.540244102, 0.806753874, 65.69918823, 0.436670482, -0.194670126, ''], ['Argentina', 6.039330006, 9.843519211, 0.906699121, 67.53870392, 0.831966162, -0.186299905, 0.305430293], ['Armenia', 4.287736416, 9.034710884, 0.697924912, 65.12568665, 0.613697052, -0.132166177, 0.246900991], ['Australia', 7.25703764, 10.71182728, 0.949957848, 72.78334045, 0.910550177, 0.301693261, 0.45340696]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers assume a fixed level of nesting (list of lists). You could (if applicable) use the following code, which uses recursion of handle deeper nested lists (lists of lists of lists, etc).

```
def nested_str_to_float(value):
    """ Converts an string to float. Value may be a single value, a list
        or even a nested list. If value is a (nested) list, all
        values in the (nested) list are evaluated to floats wherever possible.

        Args:
            value: single value of any type or a list

        Returns:
            a copy of value with all float-convertible items converted to float
    """

    # Test if value is a list, if so, recursively call nested_str_to_float
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return [nested_str_to_float(item) for item in value]

    # Try to convert to float; if possible, return float, else return value
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

By the way, [check this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python/20929881#20929881) to see what Python considers floats...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a star unpacking in a listcomp:

```
l = [['A', '1.1', '1.2'], ['B', '2.1', '2.2']]

[[i, *map(float, j)] for i, *j in l]
# [['A', 1.1, 1.2], ['B', 2.1, 2.2]]
```