# python asyncio exceptions raised from loop.create_task()

Tags: python, exception, logging, python-asyncio, python-logging

I want my code to use python `logging` to log exceptions.
In my usual code using `await`, exceptions are raised normally, so:

`try:
   await code_that_can_raise()
except Exception as e:
   logger.exception("Exception happended")`

Works fine.

However, when using 
`loop.create_task(coro())`

I'm not sure how can I catch the exception here.
Wrapping the create_task() call obviously won't work. 
What is the best solution to log every exception in the code?

Answer (score 8):

> What is the best solution to log every exception in the code?

If you control the invocation of `create_task`, but don't control the code in the `coro()`, then you can write a logging wrapper:

```
async def log_exceptions(awaitable):
    try:
        return await awaitable
    except Exception:
        logger.exception("Unhandled exception")
```

then you can call `loop.create_task(log_exceptions(coro()))`.

If you can't or don't want to wrap every `create_task`, you can call [`loop.set_exception_handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.set_exception_handler), setting the exception to your own function that will log the exception as you see fit.

Comment: It's [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797463/1113207) to use `except Exception:` instead of `except:` to avoid suppressing `KeyboardInterrupt` and similar non-errors.

Comment: Any general solution that is based on the event loop? rather than wrapping every create_task call. Since as I understand, the exception is eventually raised up to  the event loop.

Comment: @user3599803 You can use `set_exception_handler` for that purpose; see the editer answer.

Comment: how do you await in a function that is not async?

Comment: @nurettin Good catch, I've now added the missing `async`.

Comment: Can't we instead await the returned Task from "create_task" and then check its error state? Because here we seem limited to logging the error but we can't raise it upper

Comment: @EricBurel Immediately awaiting the task returned by `create_task` would defeat the purpose of calling `create_task` in the first place, which is to run the task in the background (of sorts). I.e. `await create_task(foo())` would be no better than `await foo()`. if you just write `create_task(foo())`, it means you _want_ to run `foo()` independently of what you're doing. There are several ways how you could propagate an exception raised by `foo()`, and the advice in this answer is tailored to the needs of the question.

Comment: Make sense, I've opened a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614167/bubble-up-error-from-asyncio-create-task-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Just so that it has been mentioned: `asyncio.Task` objects have the methods [`result`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.result) and [`exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.exception).
`result`:

> [...] if the coroutine raised an exception, that exception is
>   re-raised [...]

`exception`:

> [...] If the wrapped coroutine raised an exception that exception is
>   returned [...]

Given a simple setup (in Python 3.7 syntax):

```
import asyncio
tasks =[]

async def bad_test():
    raise ValueError

async def good_test():
    return

async def main():
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(bad_test()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(good_test()))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Using `result`, one could do:

```
for t in tasks:
    try:
        f = t.result()
    except ValueError as e:
        logger.exception("we're all doomed")
```

Or, using `exception`:

```
for t in tasks:
    if isinstance(t.exception(), Exception):
        logger.exception("apocalypse now")
```

However, both methods require the `Task` to be done, otherwise:

> If the Task has been cancelled, this method raises a CancelledError
>   exception.
>
> (*result*): If the Task’s result isn’t yet available, this method raises a
>   InvalidStateError exception.
>
> (*exception*): If the Task isn’t done yet, this method raises an InvalidStateError exception.

So, unlike the proposal in the other answer, the logging will not happen when the exceptions raise in the tasks, but rather when the tasks are evaluated after they completed.

Comment: What about a task that is not expected to complete? I have a task that is supposed to consume a queue forever, it finishes when we cancel it

Comment: I've tried a solution with "add_done_callback", however when raising an exception from there it doesn't "bubble up", I  can log it but it is not caught upper

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @user4815162342's solution, I created a wrapper around `log_exceptions` to avoid having to nest every coroutine inside 2 functions:

```
import asyncio
from typing import Awaitable

def create_task_log_exception(awaitable: Awaitable) -> asyncio.Task:
    async def _log_exception(awaitable):
        try:
            return await awaitable
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
    return asyncio.create_task(_log_exception(awaitable))
```

Usage:

```
create_task_log_exception(coroutine())
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use create_task but you need await it if you want to catch the exception at some point:

```
import asyncio

async def sleepError(x):
  await asyncio.sleep(x)
  print(1)
  throw_error = 1 / 0

async def sleepOk(x):
  await asyncio.sleep(x)
  print(2)

async def main():
  x = asyncio.create_task(sleepError(1))
  await sleepOk(2)
  
  """
  await x
  # print(3) bellow works without "await x", and print(1) from sleepError as well
  # You can try/except the "await x" line
  # if you "await x" without try/except, print(3) is not executed but error happens.
  # if you don't "await x" you get warning: Task exception was never retrieved
  """
  print(3)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react to the exception of a task **as soon as it occurs** you can use
`add_done_callback()` ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback )

asyncio.Task objects is an asyncio.Future like object and has the `add_done_callback()` method.

In the callback function you just have to get the `result()` of the future to provoke an exception.
with try except you can add custom handling / logging whatever.

```
import asyncio

async def sleepError(x):
  await asyncio.sleep(x)
  print(1)
  throw_error = 1 / 0

def done_callback(futr):
    try:
        rslt = futr.result()
    except Exception as exc:
        # do_something_with(exc) if you want to (like logging)
        # or just raise
        raise

async def sleepOk(x):
  await asyncio.sleep(x)
  print(2)

async def main():
  x = asyncio.create_task(sleepError(1))
  # without next line exception will only occur at end of main
  x.add_done_callback(done_callback)
  await sleepOk(2)
  print(3)

asyncio.run(main())
```

If you just want to see the exception on the console, then following callback is sufficient:

```
def done_callback(futr):
    rslt = futr.result()
```