# xlwings: how to detect whether a python function is being called from VBA module?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

### Situation

The *xlwings* package provides a convenient way to [call python functions from an excel VBA module](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html#run-python). The *xlwings* documentation gives the following basic example:

> Write the code below into a VBA module.
>
> ```
> Sub HelloWorld()
>     RunPython ("import hello; hello.world()")
> End Sub
> ```
>
> This calls the following code in `hello.py`:
>
> ```
> # hello.py
> import numpy as np
> import xlwings as xw
>
> def world():
>     wb = xw.Book.caller()
>     wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = 'Hello World!'
> ```

Trying to run the python function `world()` directly (instead of calling it from excel VBA) gives the following error message:

> Exception: Book.caller() must not be called directly. Call through
>   Excel or set a mock caller first with Book.set_mock_caller().

### Question

I would like to modify the `world()` function such that it raises a custom exception instead when being run directly. In order to achieve this I first need to determine programmatically whether the `world()` function is being run directly or being called from excel VBA (at least that's what I'd think). How could I do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: @Goyo The exception that would have to be caught here has no specific type (it's a generic `Exception`), meaning that I also can't specify a specifc exception type in a try-except clause. Aren't such catch-all try-except clauses usually [highly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797508/7306999)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the exception and then raise your own:

```
def world():
    try:
        wb = xw.Book.caller()
    except Exception:
        raise CustomException(custom_message)
    wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = 'Hello World!'
```

You are worried that `Exception` is too generic, and rightly so. But that's xlwings' fault, not yours. If it is raising a generic `Exception` that's all you are left with to catch. You could check the exception message to make sure that you are not catching the wrong exception, but that would be brittle. Error messages are usually undocumented and not to be regarded as public, stable API.

Alternatively you can fix the problem where the problem is, [xlwings' source code](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/master/xlwings/main.py#L569), and make it do what looks to me like the right thing to do: raising a more specific exception.

```
class NotFromExcelError(Exception):
    pass
```

And at the end of `caller`:

```
raise NotFromExcelError('Book.caller() must not be called directly. Call through Excel '
                        'or set a mock caller first with Book.set_mock_caller().')
```

I hope a pull request like this would be accepted because raising a bare `Exception` like it currently does looks really wrong.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks. It looks like the need for a more specific exception type was already recognized as early as 2015 (see [github issue](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/322)), but that thus far it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: The lack of further activity on that reinforces my impression that the best way of getting this fixed is doing the work yourself. It is an easy change after all and it shouldn't be hard having it merged.

Comment: A [github pull request](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/pull/1123) that could resolve the issue was made, but it is currently still pending.

Comment: Update: the pull request was rejected. The developer wanted to instead implement custom exceptions across the entire package in one go. As of now this hasn't happend yet (the issue is listed on the [xlwings 1.0 roadmap](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1993)).