# python decrement space used in memory when an item is picked up from the queue

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-management, memory-leaks, queue

at the moment my program starts producer threads and a consumer thread, all threads pick up and insert elements in a shared queue object, and keep a reference to it.

I know that the garbage collector cleans the memory when you no longer have references to the object, but my problem is another since I have to keep references to the queue to continue inserting or removing items

Starting the program I noticed that when I insert an element in the queue the memory space allocated for the queue grows together with the length of the queue, while when I take an element from the queue its size decreases instead the memory space assigned to the queue does not decrease, is there a way to decrease the memory space too?
With this problem, the allocated memory continues to grow for each inserted element until it occupies all the available memory.

UPDATE
after some research i found this, it seems to be a problem very similar to mine
https://python-forum.io/Thread-Queue-Queue-would-not-reduce-capacity-after-get
also suggest to create a new queue and swap, how can I do it efficiently?

an example of my code

Main thread creates process_queue and starts Threads

```
#this is the main thread
import queue
process_queue = ProcessQueue()
#main thread starts StartProcessThread and SendingThread, passes process_queue as param
```

ProcessQueue

```
class ProcessQueue():

    def __init__(self):
        self.q = queue.Queue()

    def put(self,elem):
        self.q.put(elem)

    def get(self):
        elem = self.q.get()
        temp = queue.Queue()

        #swap queue

        return elem

    def task_done(self):
        self.q.task_done()
```

StartProcessThread

```
class StartProcessThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, process_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.process_queue = process_queue
        #some vars

    #some methods


    def start_download(self, name):

        try:
            #starts a process
            process = Popen(
                ["path", "params"])
        except Exception as e:
            return False

        process_list = [process, name]

        self.process_queue.put(process_list)

        return True


    def task(self, url, name):
        #something

        if self.start_download(name):
            #something
            return True
        else:

            return False

    def run(self):
        # threadpoolexecutor
        executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
        while True:
            strm = #get something from db

            if str: 
                executor.submit(self.task, (url))
            else:
                sleep(10)
```

SendingThread

```
class SendingThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,process_queue):
        super(SendingThread, self).__init__()
        self.process_queue = process_queue

    def get_process(self):
        process = self.process_queue.get()
        poll = process[0].poll()
        # if poll == none process still alive
        if poll is not None:
            return process

        self.process_queue.put(process)
        return []

    def run(self):
        while True:
            process = self.get_process()
            if process:
                # do something
```

Comment: I think that if you're looking for memory efficiency on this scale, Python is not the way to go.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? As an aside, using `except Exception as e:` like you are here is bad practice. See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Comment: @AMC after some research i found this https://python-forum.io/Thread-Queue-Queue-would-not-reduce-capacity-after-get here there seems to be a problem very similar to mine, so the minimal reproducible example can be found there, also among the answers they suggest to create a new queue and swap it, so how can I swap efficiently the queues? I will update the post soon