# NameError: name 'all_df' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, undefined, nameerror

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 14 2017
Modified on Wed Aug 16 2017
Author: Yanfei Wu
Get the past 500 S&P 500 stocks data
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

def get_ticker_and_sector(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'):
    """ 
    get the s&p 500 stocks from Wikipedia:
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies

    ---
    return: a dictionary with ticker names as keys and sectors as values 
    """

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

    # we only want to parse the first table of this wikipedia page
    table = soup.find('table')

    sp500 = {}
    # loop over the rows and get ticker symbol and sector name
    for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:]: 
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        ticker = tds[0].text
        sector = tds[3].text
        sp500[ticker] = sector

    return sp500

def get_stock_data(ticker, start_date, end_date):
    """ get stock data from google with stock ticker, start and end dates """
    data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'google', start_date, end_date)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    """ get the stock data from the past 5 years """
    # end_date = datetime.now()
    end_date = datetime(2017, 8, 14)
    start_date = datetime(end_date.year - 5, end_date.month , end_date.day)

    sp500 = get_ticker_and_sector()
    sp500['SPY'] = 'SPY' # also include SPY as reference
    print('Total number of tickers (including SPY): {}'.format(len(sp500))) 

    bad_tickers =[]
    for i, (ticker, sector) in enumerate(sp500.items()):
        try:
            stock_df = get_stock_data(ticker, start_date, end_date)
            stock_df['Name'] = ticker
            stock_df['Sector'] = sector
            if stock_df.shape[0] == 0:
                bad_tickers.append(ticker)
            #output_name = ticker + '_data.csv'
            #stock_df.to_csv(output_name)
            if i == 0:
                all_df = stock_df
            else:
                all_df = all_df.append(stock_df)
        except:
            bad_tickers.append(ticker)
    print(bad_tickers)

    all_df.to_csv('./data/all_sp500_data_2.csv')

    """ Write failed queries to a text file """
    if len(bad_tickers) > 0:
        with open('./data/failed_queries_2.txt','w') as outfile:
            for ticker in bad_tickers:
                outfile.write(ticker+'\n')
```

Comment: You should never use a bare except clause. This is likely hiding some error from you.

Comment: Elle, could you edit this question so there is some description in the body? You have two questions that have closed already, and this one only needs one more close vote. Please edit this promptly to try saving it from being closed. Your account is liable to hit into an automatic question ban soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your `try/except` block. It is [good style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797508/12568761) to always catch a specific exception, not just blindly throw `except` statements after a long block of code. The problem with this approach, as demonstrated in your problem, is that if you have an unrelated or unexpected error, you won't know about it. In this case, this is the exception I get from running your code:

```
NotImplementedError: data_source='google' is not implemented
```

I'm not sure what that means, but it looks like the [pandas_datareader.data.DataReader docs](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-access) have good information about how to use that DataReader correctly.

Comment: yeah i know i change it to 
data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
NameError: name 'all_df' is not defined :/

Comment: If you fix your try/except statement, you'll notice that the reason `all_df` doesn't ever get defined is because it is only first created once the first `stock_df` is found. Since your DataReader always throws an error, you never reach that point.