# Python text file into directory list

Tags: python

I needed help to add into directory below text file. Can anyone can help me to do it? I tried
**I have data.txt like below:?**

```
A1234 161
A1234 106
A456  185
A456  108
037   125

**Output:**
directory = {
"A1234": [161,106],
"A456": [185,108],
"037": [125],
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
output_dict = {}
data = list(map(
    lambda a:a.strip().split(),
    open("data.csv").readlines()
))
for k,v in data:
    try:
        output_dict[k].append(v)
    except:
        output_dict[k] = [v]
output_dict
```

Output:

> {'A1234': ['161', '106'], 'A456': ['185', '108'], '037': ['125']}

Comment: This works, but using a bare exception clause is generally considered to be a bad practice. See here for more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements

Comment: For above file your code works fine. Thank you. But when I use other file which has 9375 rows of data, Its throw error like "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

Answer (score 1):

**data.txt:**

```
A1234 161
A1234 106
A456  185
A456  108
037   125
```

From file to dictionary:

```py
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data_lines = file.readlines()

directory = {}

for line in data_lines:
    a, *b = line.split()
    # convert all elements of b into integers:
    b = [int(item) for item in b]
    if directory.get(a, False):
        if isinstance(b, list):
            directory[a].extend(b)
        else:
            directory[a].append(b)
    else:
        directory[a] = list(b)

print(directory)
# {'A1234': [161, 106], 'A456': [185, 108], '037': [125]}
# prettified:
"""
{
    'A1234': [161, 106],
    'A456': [185, 108],
    '037': [125]
}
"""
```

Comment: For above file your code works fine. Thank you. But when I use other file which has 9375 rows of data, Its throw error like "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

Comment: I'm trying to do ICD mapping file dynamically added into directory.

Comment: Ok, I think `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` has nothing to do with the amount of data. It has to do with the line `a, b = line.split()` : it's unpacking the line split (a list) in two variables. Does your data file contain lines with more than  2 'words' ? (I guess so. If so, show me an exemple I will adapt the code)  
See more info [here](https://itsmycode.com/valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-2/#:~:text=ValueError%3A%20too%20many%20values%20to%20unpack%20(expected%202)%20occurs,you%20get%20a%20value%20error.)

Comment: I tested the code with the example input data just by changing the first line to `A1234 161 55` and that's throwing the same error. I edited my answer, now it should work fine with any amount of 'words' or 'numbers' per line :)

Comment: Awesome, Stijn B Sir, It works. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Stijn B, 
in answer, How can I remove?
{
 "A1234": [161,106],
"A456": [185,108],
"037": [125], 
}

Comment: Thanks. You mean how to make this `['161', '106']` like this `[161, 106] ` ? (goingi from string to integers)

Comment: Correct, String to int

Comment: @ShaileshPatel answer edited. Now it outputs lists of integers

Comment: Hi SB, Thank you,
I got this error,
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'

Comment: Well if you have something like `A1234 161 A85` in your file it will obviously not work (Python cannot convert `A85` to an integer). Please provide the line which is producing that error

Comment: Hi SB, Thank you, Your code is perfectly fine, my data had issue, I fixed it. Some data has space like A1234 A 161 in it. I change it to A1234A 161.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pandas solution. First we employ read_csv() and use one or more spaces as our delimiter. We need to specify string (object) dtypes to get string values for the list items as in your output. If you want ints, you could skip the dtype argument and pandas will infer them. Next we groupby the fist column (0) and convert the values in column 1 to a list with apply. Finally, we use .to_dict to get a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('dir.txt', header=None, sep=r"[ ]{1,}", dtype='object')

directory = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list).to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'037': ['125'], 'A1234': ['161', '106'], 'A456': ['185', '108']}
```

Comment: For above file your code works fine. Thank you. But when I use other file which has 9375 rows of data, Its throw error like "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

Comment: You likely have some irregularities in your .txt file, but it's tricky to account for them without seeing the full data. Can you post a larger sample?